# How to copy entire file to clipboard together with line numbers in Vim

Tags: vim, line-numbers

I enabled vim-gtk, opened a file, did `:set nu`, but the command `:%y+` does not copy the line numbers to the clipboard.

That may be resolved in visual mode (I do not know how to use it), but sometimes files are very long and I guess it is impractical.

Also does `:set nonumber` have a shorter alias like `:set number` has `:set nu`?

Comment: line numbers are not part of the file, or the buffer persea, so don't think you can copy them, but you should be be able to filter / add them  see  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_line_numbers

Answer (score 3):

To copy the entire file with line numbers to the `"+` register (which is `CLIPBOARD` buffer under X11) you may use:

```
:redir @+ | silent %# | redir END
```

Answer (score 1):

`:set nonumber` is the same as `:set nonu`.

Line numbers will not be copied. But, if you copy the entire file, just enable line numbers where you paste in.